# Salesforce Phone Validation Rule should contains + at startig and - ( ) at any place mid start end and number

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule, phone

I'm trying to create a validation rule for Phone Numbers. Say, I have Phone Number fields that should be checked if the values meet the following requirements:

`+` at starting
`-` at any place it shoud accept Like : -999 999-9898 OR 999-999-9999 OR 999-999-9999
( ) at any place it should accept Like : (999) 999 9999 or 999 (999) 999 OR 999 999 (999)
0-9 numberic only

(989) 898 3232
982 -872 8982
+(878) 232 8982
-(232) 349 0923
999 (323) 8923
983-983-9343
+232 902 -2323

```
AND(
NOT(REGEX( Phone, "^\\+?-?([0-9 ]+[-]?[0-9 ]+[-]?[0-9 ]+)$" )),
OR(NOT(REGEX(Phone,"^((\\+)?\\s?\\(\\d+\\)\\s?\\d+\\-?\\d+)?$"))),
NOT(ISBLANK(Phone)),
NOT(ISNULL(Phone))
)
```

Thanks please help me with this

Comment: Doesn't the standard `Phone` field (of type `Phone`, or custom fields utilizing the `Phone` field type) already do all (or most) of this for you?

Comment: Hi @DerekF there is no any validation on the standard Phone field